# JavaFX: type safe TilePane / ListView with tiles

Tags: javafx

edited:
OK, I think I mostly solved my own problem, or at least I've got something that works, but it feels pretty hacky and isn't type safe... I basically just added some logic to a TilePane to get it to do what I want, but it's a lot of custom code. Not sure if this was the right way to do it, but it does work... Posting my solution in case anyone has feedback or a similar question in the future. Is this OK?

Mostly I'm wondering, is it OK for me to cast Nodes to CardViews when I click them inside the TilePanes? Could I do this better with ListView? And is there a way to do this with a different component that will instantiate a minimum of off screen nodes?

Original:
I'm working on a JavaFX card game and I was wondering how I can get a type-safe TilePane, if that makes sense. Right now I'm working on the deck building part of the game. I want to display cards generated from a list of Cards, and I want to display them in rows of 3, if possible. I want the layout of a TilePane, but the type safety of a ListView.

ListView is type-safe, but its elements can only be displayed as a list (either horizontally or vertically) while TilePane gives me exactly the layout I want but isn't type safe.

Is there anyway I can get both? Should I just make a custom component?

Here is a (more complete) Minimum Reproducible Example.

DeckBuilderControllerMRE

```java
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.MapChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableMap;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class DeckBuilderControllerMRE {
    @FXML TilePane availableCards, cardsInDeck;

    //maps from a list of available cards to the number of those cards in the deck
    ObservableMap<Card, Integer> currentDeckMap = FXCollections.observableMap(new HashMap<>());
    //these map from card data objects to view nodes, which is wasteful but works...
    HashMap<Card, CardView> availableViewsMap = new HashMap<>(), deckViewsMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void initialize() {
        //dummy card data
        ArrayList<Card> allCards = new ArrayList<>();
        allCards.add(new Card("sword guy", 5));
        allCards.add(new Card("arrow man", 3));
        allCards.add(new Card("shablagoo", 10000000));
        allCards.add(new Card("guy # 4", 4));
        allCards.add(new Card("Dr. Evil", 7));
        allCards.add(new Card("one more", -5));

        //this maps cards to total avaialble, because you're only allowed to have a certain number of each card
        HashMap<Card, Integer> cardQuantities = new HashMap<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < allCards.size(); i++)
            cardQuantities.put(allCards.get(i), i);

        //instantiate card views and add to view maps
        //also sets up binding for quantity labels
        for(Card card : allCards){
            currentDeckMap.put(card, 0);

            CardView availableView = card.getCardView();
            availableView.quantityLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("Quantity Available: ",
                    Bindings.subtract(cardQuantities.get(card), Bindings.integerValueAt(currentDeckMap, card))));

            availableViewsMap.put(card, availableView);
            availableCards.getChildren().add(availableView);

            CardView deckView = card.getCardView();
            deckView.quantityLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat("Quantity in deck: ", Bindings.integerValueAt(currentDeckMap, card)));
            deckViewsMap.put(card, deckView);
        }

        //clicking available cards adds them to your deck
        availableCards.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            //check if I clicked the container instead of a card
            if(event.getTarget() == availableCards)
                return;

            //otherwise I bubble up to the container node CardView
            Node node = (Node) event.getTarget();
            while(node.getParent() != availableCards)
                node = node.getParent();

            //and then I cast the nodes to CardViews
            //which is the part I think might need fixing
            CardView selectedView = (CardView) node;
            Card selectedCard = selectedView.card;


            //and then I update the map which updates the quantityLabel
            currentDeckMap.put(selectedCard, currentDeckMap.get(selectedCard) + 1);

            event.consume();
        });

        //and this does the same thing but removes them
        cardsInDeck.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, event -> {
            if(event.getTarget() == cardsInDeck)
                return;

            Node node = (Node) event.getTarget();
            while(node.getParent() != cardsInDeck)
                node = node.getParent();

            CardView selectedView = (CardView) node;
            Card selectedCard = selectedView.card;

            currentDeckMap.put(selectedCard, currentDeckMap.get(selectedCard) - 1);

            event.consume();
        });

        currentDeckMap.addListener((MapChangeListener<Card, Integer>) change -> {
            Card card = change.getKey();
            int stillAvailable = cardQuantities.get(card) - currentDeckMap.get(card);

            if(stillAvailable == 0)
                availableCards.getChildren().remove(availableViewsMap.get(card));
            if(stillAvailable == 1 && !availableCards.getChildren().contains(availableViewsMap.get(card)))
                availableCards.getChildren().add(availableViewsMap.get(card));

            if(currentDeckMap.get(card) == 0)
                cardsInDeck.getChildren().remove(deckViewsMap.get(card));
            else if(currentDeckMap.get(card) == 1 && !cardsInDeck.getChildren().contains(deckViewsMap.get(card)))
                cardsInDeck.getChildren().add(deckViewsMap.get(card));
        });
    }

    class Card {
        String cardName;
        int cardStrength;

        Card(String n, int s){
            cardName = n;
            cardStrength = s;
        }

        public CardView getCardView(){
            return new CardView(this);
        }
    }

    //cards usually have images and stuff, but this is enough to see what I'm doing
    //also, CardView extends some kind of container node, currently VBox, but that might change later
    class CardView extends VBox {
        Card card;
        Label nameLabel, strengthLabel, quantityLabel;

        CardView(Card card){
            this.card = card;
            nameLabel = new Label(card.cardName);
            strengthLabel = new Label(card.cardStrength + "");
            quantityLabel = new Label();
            this.getChildren().addAll(nameLabel, strengthLabel, quantityLabel);
        }
    }

}
```

The fxml looks like this (it's a border pane with TilePanes wrapped in ScrollPanes on the left and right sides). (You might need to add a package identifier to the fx:controller attribute. Everything else should work though).

deck_builder.fxml

```
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="900.0" prefWidth="1300.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/10.0.2-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="DeckBuilderControllerMRE">
   <left>
      <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" minHeight="-Infinity" minViewportHeight="200.0" minViewportWidth="400.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefViewportHeight="200.0" prefViewportWidth="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <TilePane fx:id="availableCards" hgap="10.0" prefColumns="3" tileAlignment="TOP_LEFT" vgap="10.0" />
         </content>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </ScrollPane>
   </left>
   <right>
      <ScrollPane hbarPolicy="NEVER" minHeight="-Infinity" minViewportHeight="200.0" minViewportWidth="400.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="200.0" prefViewportHeight="200.0" prefViewportWidth="400.0" prefWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <TilePane fx:id="cardsInDeck" hgap="10.0" prefColumns="3" tileAlignment="TOP_LEFT" vgap="10.0" />
         </content>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </ScrollPane>
   </right>
</BorderPane>
```

and this is my main method (basically just loads and displays the fxml)

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args)
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        window = primaryStage;
        window.setTitle("Card Game");
        window.setScene(new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("layouts/deck_builder.fxml")), sceneWidth, sceneHeight));
        window.show();
    }
}
```

This is my first time posting on Stack Overflow, so really any feedback about how I can improve this thing is welcome, although I'm kind of trying to practice rapid development here, so minor optimizations aren't really a priority.

Thanks for your help / time.

Comment: You could display three cards per cell in a `ListView`, you'd just have to create a class which represents three cards (could simply use a `List`, but that won't be as clear) and configure the cell factory to return a custom `ListCell` implementation which knows how to display three cards.

Comment: As for `TilePane` not being type-safe: Typically views are somewhat, if not fully, "dumb". Create a type-safe model and simply have the view display that model—research architectures such as MVC, MVP, and MVVM. That all being said, a [mre] may help us better help you.

Comment: You could look at `ControlsFX` `GridView`. https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html

Comment: OK, thanks for your help.

So, if views are usually dumb, does it matter if it's not type-safe? Right now what I'm doing is I have 2 horitzontal TilePanes which I'm adding StackPanes too which become the cards / tiles. Then when I click a card I just cast it down from Node to StackPane. Is that ok? Feels kinda sloppy, but I think it works...

Comment: Sedrick, I might use GridView, but right now I don't have to import any external libraries. Seems like a pain.

Comment: "Then when I click a card I just cast it down from Node to StackPane". That ideally should not be necessary, though it depends on what exactly you're trying to do. When you click on a card—or more specifically, the view that's displaying the card—you should update the model. What that update is will depend on what clicking on the card means for your application. For instance, if clicking a card means it should "flip" then update the model to indicate the card is now flipped. Then the view _reacts_ to the new flipped state and updates itself to reflect that new state.

Comment: Check out [event-driven programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) and the [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern). That all said, you may still need to cast down to `StackPane`, again depending on what you're actually trying to do. If you could provide a [mre] demonstrating you're goal and the problem then we may be able to offer more satisfactory help. You can add such an example by [edit]ing your question. And a note about replying in comments: [How do comment @replies work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/).

Comment: @Slaw ok, thank you very much! much appreciated. I've added a minimum reproducible example. I'm trying to follow the MVC pattern here, and the currentDeck ObservableMap holds most of the relevent data. ListView might give me the behavior I want for tracking CardViews, but I would have to add some custom code to make the layout look the way I want. Not sure what the right move is here.

Comment: actually .. no, you have not added a [mcve] - what happens if you throw that code (without any further context) into a new project in your ide? Right, it won't even compile, let alone run.

Comment: @kleopatra ok, my b... I thought minimal meant skipping things like getting some objects from a factory. I did not check the definition...

I added some dummy data and class definitions which should make things clearer. I think I solved my own problem, but if you want to check it out I think this should compile for you now. Mostly I was just wondering, from a design perspective, the best way to get the layout and behavior I want.

Comment: @Slaw no rush if you're busy or anything, but I added a much better example which I think should give you a better idea what's going on. I think I've solved my problem, but if you had any ideas for improvement I think there's probably some room for some :)